# Can you interleave variadic parameters in call sites?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

Is it possible to interleave template parameters inside of function call sites?

I effectively want to do implement the following, but I don't know how (psuedo code):

```
template <size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
void foo(const Things *things)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(indices) == sizeof...(Ts));
    constexpr n = sizeof...(Ts);
    bar(
      indices[0], parse<Ts[0]>(things[0]),
      indices[1], parse<Ts[1]>(things[1]),
      ...
      indices[n-1], parse<Ts[n-1]>(things[n-1]));
}
```

Note: I know the following can be done (psuedo code):

```
template <size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
void foo(const Things *things)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(indices) == sizeof...(Ts));
    constexpr n = sizeof...(Ts);
    bar(
      indices[0], indices[1], ..., indices[n-1],
      parse<Ts[0]>(things[0]),
      parse<Ts[1]>(things[1]),
      ...
      parse<Ts[n-1]>(things[n-1]));
}
```

A partial solution I came up with is to add a swizzling component:

```
template <typename Func>
decltype(auto) swizzle()
{
    return Func();
}

template <typename Func, typename T0>
decltype(auto) swizzle(size_t i0, T0 &&t0)
{
    return Func(i0, std::forward<T0>(t0));
}

template <typename Func, typename T0, typename T1>
decltype(auto) swizzle(size_t i0, size_t i1, T0 &&t0, T1 &&t1)
{
    return Func(i0, std::forward<T0>(t0), i1, std::forward<T1>(t1));
}
```

but I think I have to manually write each case per arity I want to consider.

Comment: Is there any possibility of changing the signature of `bar`? Perhaps grouping the two pieces of data into a single type?

Comment: @chris I have a working solution that doesn't interleave, but for my use case it leads to a slightly uglier API usage. Regardless of a workaround, I would love to know how to solve the question if possible. My only stab at it is to manually specialize some "swizzling" function wrappers. The downside is that I have to fix a max arity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```cpp
template <size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
void foo(const Things *things)
{
    std::apply([](auto...args) {
        bar(args...);
    }, std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(indices, parse<Ts>(*(things++)))...));
}
```

If `bar` is a lambda instead of a function template, you can just pass `bar` directly as the first argument to `std::apply`.

If you want to avoid copying the return values of `parse<Ts>(*(things++))`, you can use `std::forward_as_tuple` instead of `std::make_tuple`.

One slightly more verbose alternative if the `*(things++)` makes you uncomfortable is to use `std::index_sequence`:

```cpp
template <size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
void foo(const Things *things)
{
    [=]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        std::apply([](auto...args) {
            bar(args...);
        }, std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(indices, parse<Ts>(things[Is]))...));
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Time to try it out. Any concerns needed about the evaluation order of `things++`? If there are, it's easy enough for me to encode the index statically with each `T` in `Ts`.

Comment: Shouldn't `*(things++)` be `things[indices]`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that would not be the same as the psuedo-code in the question, no. `indices[n]` is not the same as `n`.

Comment: @ThomasEding had already thought of that question before you posted, see the edit

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question. I thought `indices` where supposed to be used on `things` to pick specific `Things`s .

Comment: Ok, I got a running example. Sorry I blundered with the illegal `foo` signature using double parameter packs. (Fixed by using `index_sequence<indices...>` and partial template specialization to extract match the `indices...`)
https://godbolt.org/z/P3MdWjq5M

Comment: @ThomasEding you don't need a `struct FooImpl`, you can just use a lambda to extract the packs from both index sequences at the same time: https://godbolt.org/z/Ka9qd6ePc

Comment: `*(things++)` is indeed problematic as evaluation order is not guaranteed.